# Trying to set up mailto: link

Tags: javascript, php, html-email

I have a webpage that has a form to insert vendor data, once inserted the company name is the placed into a select box.  when the company is selected a table is called with all the vendor information.

My problem is the 
the vendor_email is called from a php script, is there a way to make the value of the id insert into a mailto: function.

```
 <tbody id="records">
    <td id="vendor_company"></td>
    <td id="vendor_rep"></td>
    <td id="vendor_email"></td>
</tbody>
<div class="row" id="no_records"><div class="col-sm-4">Plese select vendor name to view details</div></div>
```

here is my php and js  code

```
<?php
include_once("Database/db_connect.php");
if($_REQUEST['empid']) {
$sql = "SELECT id, companyName, repName, venderEmail FROM vender_contact 
WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($conn));
$data = array();
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
$data = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
echo 0;
  }
 ?>
```

my js code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 // code to get all records from table via select box
 $("#vendors_data").change(function() {
 var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
 var dataString = 'empid='+ id;

 $.ajax({
url:"getVendor.php",
dataType: "json",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(vendorData) {
if(vendorData) {
$("#heading").show();
$("#no_records").hide();
$("#vendor_company").text(vendorData.companyName);
$("#vendor_rep").text(vendorData.repName);
$("#vendor_email").text(vendorData.venderEmail);
$("#records").show();
} else {
$("#heading").hide();
$("#records").hide();
$("#no_records").show();
}
}
});
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible! You simply need to use **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** instead of **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**.

Note that the `mailto` comes on the `href` attribute, which is unique to the `<a>` tag. As such, you'll want to place your `<a href=""></a>` inside of your `<td id="vendor_email"></td>`:

```
$("#vendor_email").html("<a href='mailto:" + vendorData.vendorEmail + "'>" + vendorData.vendorEmail + "</a>");
```

Which will render as something like:

```js
vendorData = {};
vendorData.vendorEmail = 'test@test.com';

$("#vendor_email").html("<a href='mailto:" + vendorData.vendorEmail + "'>" + vendorData.vendorEmail + "</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="vendor_email"></div>
```

In addition to this, please be aware that your MySQLi is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and also ensure that your database user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) in order to prevent this.

You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfect Thanks,   Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery's [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method you can insert html like so:

`$( '#vendor_email' ).html( '<a href="mailto:' + vendorData.vendorEmail + '">' + vendorData.vendorEmail + '</a>' );`

By the way, I couldn't help but notice that you've spelled vendor as "vender" in `venderEmail`.